# What happens if I use y_pred as the custom loss function in keras? Shouldn't this always work as y_pred will always be differentiable?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am planning to use something of this sort.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred)
```

I want to know if this is `fail-proof`.

Why am I doing this? The idea behind using `y_pred` as a loss function to maximize a variable `r` by setting the output of the model as `-r`. Thus, reducing the `loss-function` `y_pred` means reducing `-r` which means increasing `r`.

`r` is a function of `matrix X` which I will set as one of the layers in the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, the functionality of an Optimizer during Back Propagation of Deep Neural Networks is to adjust the Weights of the Layers of Neural Network in order to Minimize the Loss Function to its best possible extent.

So, if you use **`y_pred`** as Custom Loss Function, Optimizer will try its best to Minimize the **`y_pred`**, which might not give Expected Results, because, 
-(**`Less Value`**) will not result in **Maximum Value**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could be a bit clearer about the reason why you are doing this. If you don't use the y_true to compute the error loss, you may not need a ML model at all. From what I understand here, you just want a model to predict the highest value possible for whatever input.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your reply to this question would fit better in the comment section right underneath the question as your reply is not an answer but more a question.

Comment: Hello, that is what I tried to do, but to comment a question i need a higher reputation.